# Finding Cells in Column that begin with "SS" and shifting row to left

Tags: vba, excel

I have have copied a pdf that needs to be sorted out. I have spec's (SS####) in column A and misc writing in B-H. The problem is some of the specs ended up in column B so I want to search for all cells that being with SS, and then shift the entire row over. I have tried using autofilter and selecting visible cells, along with .find to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

```
Sub Test()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Sheet = Sheets("Original Index Goes Here")

Dim rng As Range, sel As Range, selrange As String, r As Long


Set rng = Range("B1:B10000")


rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=SS*", _
             Operator:=xlAnd, visibledropdown:=True
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0) _
            .Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

End Sub
```

This selects the cell in column B for each of the four shown below, but I don't know how to grab the rest of the row and shift it right. ()

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3mRt.png)

Comment: Sort on ColB to bring all the SS together: select those and drag to the left.

Comment: So using Vba, how do I select the rows that happen to get sorted, and then shift them over. Cannot shift more than one at once. Can specify row number because it can be anywhere from row 3 to row 10000.

Comment: If this is not just something you need to do once, you would first write a loop to run through the data and look for "SS" in ColB.  Did you try to write something like that?   Typically here people like to see some kind of attempt when someone is asking for code: your existing code (even if it doesn't work) along with a description of what errors you got, is always useful.

Comment: I added both code i have tried and excel. Sorry this is my first time using this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it will search column B for anything with like "SS" and if found delete the cell to the left which  is A and shift the whole row left.

```
Sub findSS()
Dim getLastRow As Long
getLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To getLastRow
    If Range("B" & i) Like "*SS*" Then
        Range("A" & i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

UPDATE, will find "SS" in column D or if you want it to find in any column just change the "D" to which ever column you want and it will get the SS and insert a row and put it there.

```
Sub findSS()
Dim getLastRow As Long
Dim columnLetter As String
getLastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
columnLetter = "D"

For i = 1 To getLastRow
    If Range(columnLetter & i) Like "*SS*" Then
        Range(columnLetter & i).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Being a beginner, I have a couple questions. First off, why do you have the & i in the range?

Comment: the " & i " is to loop each row, i is the place holder for each row. for example, B & i = B1, B2, B3.....

Comment: Ok so lets say i have an SS in column D, and there is data to the left of it. Could i add row below, then delete and shift down and left?

Comment: You're going away from your original post question. If this answers your original question, mark it as answer and ask a new question please.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It has been marked. I cannot ask more questions for a couple days due to poor formatting when originally asking the question.

Comment: if by what you are asking, if there is data to the left of column D lets say column a,b,c have data and you want to shift all cells starting with column d to the left to column b and override any existing data in those columns?

Comment: If there is data in A,B and C and SS in D. Could you insert a row beneath it and move D onward into that row. Thus saving the data in A, B and C

Answer (score 0):

Try below to delete column a cell and shift left:

```
dim i as long, lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 2 to lr 'assumes row 1 is headers
    if left(cells(i,2),2)="SS" then cells(i,1).delete Shift:=xltoleft
next i
```

Try below to add a blank cell and shift to right:

```
dim i as long, lr as long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 2 to lr 'assumes row 1 is headers
    if left(cells(i,2),2)="SS" then cells(i,1).insert Shift:=xltoright
next i
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks for your response